# No vote issue due to add same value multiple time in ehcache in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ehcache, spring-transactions

My issue is I am handle ehcache by my self not using hibernate.

**eg**. Whenever I required any Object First I get from cache if not found then get from db and put into cache.so, next time It is available in cache.

**issue** : when two thread try to get that object at that time first of all both have not found object in cache. first both get from db and then both try to put object in cache.At that time second thread gave error of No vote.
can you please suggest any best way to manage ehcache manually. If you not getting my question feel free to contact.

**Error**

```
org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA
transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested
exception is javax.transaction.RollbackException: Prepare: NO vote    
  at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1026)
  at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
  at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:518)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
```

Comment: Please use code formatting for errors and stack traces, NOT blockquote.

Comment: Do you use the @Cacheable Annotation? There is a sync property, so only one thread creates a missing key on the cache.

Comment: C.Weber This issue is not related @cacheable Annotation. I clearly mention that two thread doing same process

Answer (score 0):

This exception means that when a transaction is requested to commit but has already been rolled back due to a timeout.You can increase the transaction timeout to resolve this.

Comment: Thank you for reply. This is not time out issue. but when two thread add same data in cache at that time cache state is became inconsistent. so, second thread give no vote error.